# How to use group and sum same data based on different criteria on same table

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum data in a table.

Data in my table:

```
Month   Osl         Sale
10      8-02-01-01  38440.5
10      8-02-01-03  14961
10      8-03-02-01  10388.3
10      8-05-04-01  81666.6
10      8-05-04-05  29431.8
10      8-07-01-09  9821.4
10      8-09-01-01  7567.5
```

And my expected output is:

[image]

Comment: Do not include images or links ! Instead include your samples directly in your question as `formatted text`. Also, always tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Please copy-paste the elements of the table in the second case here. Images of code/errors/information are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I think `union all` is the simplest method:

```
select month, osl, sale
from t
union all
select month, left(osl, 7), sum(sale)
from t
group by month, left(osl, 7);
```

Not all databases support `left()`.  In those that don't, either `substr()` or `substring()` can extract the first seven characters.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of your RDMS, but I would suggest something along the lines of:

```sql
select * from table1
union all
select t.month, left(t.osl, len(t.osl)-3), sum(t.sale)
from table1 t
group by t.month, left(t.osl, len(t.osl)-3)
```

Change `table1` to your table name as appropriate.